# How to create a custom module after installing magento docker image?

Tags: module, development, customize

I have successfully set up a magento docker image with the help of Adobe DevDocs.
But when I tried to create a custom module under the directory of /app/code. I met lots of error when I tried to deploy the new created module.

What I am confused on is whether the development workflow is the same as the normal magento setup environment with installation all requirements?

Where should I found the normal php magento command???

Comment: `bin/magento list` will give you a list of all available commands in magento. That being said, you should be more clear about your issue, what are these lots of errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, They are the same on the normal magento. Maybe you have error on your Module.

> Where should I found the normal php magento command???

You can do normal php magento commands by entering bash:

```
docker-compose run --rm deploy bash
```